# Проблемы со сборкой jom и Qt5 из исходников на Windows

Tags: windows, qt5, windows-10, сборка

Всех приветствую.

Не получается собрать jom из исодников. Нахожусь в директории c:\jom\jom-build, а в директории c:\jom\jom лежит сам исходник. Делаю примерно всё по гайду от сюда:
https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/jom.git/tree/README.
Соответственно, я задаю в консоль следующую команду:

```
cmake c:\jom\jom -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:\jom -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\jom\jom-install
```

Но получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

---

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
version 5.2.0) with any of the following names:

Qt5Config.cmake
qt5-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/jom/jom-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

Где я должен взять Qt5Config.cmake или qt5-config.cmake и зачем они нужны при сборке jom? У меня есть исходники qt5, но там таких файлов нет. Ещё пробовал с генератором "Visual Studio 16 2019", но результат тот же. Операционка Windows 10. И ещё у меня вопрос зачем нужна и что делает эта команда:

```
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:PATH=X:\build-jom\qt\bin\qmake.exe
```

Я находил подобный вопрос на одном из форумов, но ничего особо там не понял.

Вообще я изначально хотел собрать Qt5 из исходников. Там тоже пока ничего не получается. Нужно экспериментировать, но утилита nmake работает в 1 потоке, поэтому я и хотел установить jom, чтобы разобраться с установкой уже самого Qt5 быстрее.

Comment: https://the-codeslinger.com/2020/10/05/cmake-on-windows-10-with-qt5-error-cmake_prefix_path/

Comment: Я всё же не пойму. У меня должен быть Qt5 установлен или как? У меня только исходники от него лежат. Там есть папка с названием "mingw", но она лежит очень глубоко, никаких файлов с расширением .cmake в ней нет, добавление её в CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ничего не даёт.